# Replace Java Applet with GWT

Tags: javascript, java, html, gwt, applet

Hi I have the following class which would like to replace with stjs, but it seems it does not work for me, as stjs does not cover all applet libraries, any though if this is can be done thru stjs or any other technology? Thanks in advance

```
package org.stjs.examples.hello;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;
import java.text.BreakIterator;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class DataCache
  extends Applet
  implements ActionListener
{
  private static final String APPLET_VERSION = "1.6.0";
  private static final int MSG_WIN_HEIGHT = 179;
  private static final int MSG_WIN_WIDTH = 288;
  private static final String MSG_WIN_ETITLE = "Error Message";
  private static final String MSG_WIN_MTITLE = "Information Message";
  public String m_error = "";
  public String m_message = "";
  public String m_currCacheString = "";
  public StringBuffer m_currXMLCache = null;
  public Hashtable m_currHashCache = null;
  private String m_commandKey;
  private Hashtable m_XMLCache = new Hashtable();
  private Hashtable m_hashCache = new Hashtable();
  private String m_key = "";
  private String m_keyList = "";
  private String m_file = "";
  private String m_dataDir = "";
  private String m_autoLoad = "TRUE";
  private String m_servletURL = "";
  private String m_debugApplet = "";
  private Frame m_msgWindow;
  private TextArea m_msgText;
  private Button m_msgButton;
  private FontMetrics m_msgMetrics;
  private int m_msgTextHeight;

  public void destroy()
  {
    this.m_msgWindow.dispose();
  }

  public void init()
  {
    createErrorWindow();
    alertStatus("applet version: 1.6.0", 'D');

    this.m_debugApplet = getAppParam("debugApplet");
    this.m_autoLoad = getAppParam("autoLoad");
    this.m_commandKey = getAppParam("commandKey");
    String ls = getAppParam("loadStatic");
    String dataDir = getAppParam("dataDir");

    this.m_servletURL = getAppParam("servletURL");
    URL url = getCodeBase();
    int port = url.getPort();
    if (this.m_debugApplet.equals("TRUE")) {
      System.out.println("url: " + this.m_servletURL);
    } else if (port != -1) {
      this.m_servletURL = ("http://" + url.getHost() + ":" + port + this.m_servletURL);
    } else {
      this.m_servletURL = ("http://" + url.getHost() + this.m_servletURL);
    }
    setDataDir(dataDir);
    if (!this.m_autoLoad.toUpperCase().equals("FALSE")) {
      if ((ls.equals("")) || (ls.toUpperCase().equals("FALSE")))
      {
        alertStatus("loading non-static...", 'D');
        loadAllData(false);
      }
      else if (ls.toUpperCase().equals("TRUE"))
      {
        alertStatus("loading static...", 'D');
        openAllData(false);
      }
    }
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    String s = e.getActionCommand();
    if (s.equals("OK")) {
      this.m_msgWindow.hide();
    }
  }

  private void createErrorWindow()
  {
    this.m_msgWindow = new Frame("New Title");
    Panel p1 = new Panel();
    Panel p2 = new Panel();
    Panel p3 = new Panel();

    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));


    this.m_msgText = new TextArea("New Message", 3, 40, 1);
    this.m_msgText.setEditable(false);
    this.m_msgText.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 0, 8));
    this.m_msgMetrics = this.m_msgText.getFontMetrics(this.m_msgText.getFont());
    p2.add(this.m_msgText);
    p1.add(p2);

    this.m_msgButton = new Button(" OK ");
    this.m_msgButton.addActionListener(this);
    this.m_msgButton.setActionCommand("OK");
    p3.add(this.m_msgButton);
    p1.add(p3);

    this.m_msgWindow.add(p1);
    this.m_msgWindow.pack();

    Toolkit t = this.m_msgWindow.getToolkit();
    this.m_msgTextHeight = this.m_msgMetrics.getHeight();

    this.m_msgWindow.setBounds(new Rectangle(
      t.getScreenSize().width / 2 - 144, 
      t.getScreenSize().height / 2 - 89, 
      288, 
      179));
  }

  public void setDataDir(String s)
  {
    try
    {
      if ((s != null) && (s.length() > 0))
      {
        if (s.charAt(s.length() - 1) != '\\') {
          s = s + "\\";
        }
        this.m_dataDir = s;
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      alertStatus(e.getMessage(), 'E');
      alertStatus(s, 'E');
    }
  }

  private String getAppParam(String s)
  {
    String param = getParameter(s);
    if (param == null) {
      return "";
    }
    return param;
  }

  private String alertStatus(String source, Exception e, char status)
  {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    return alertStatus(source + " -- " + e.getMessage(), status);
  }

  private String alertStatus(String s, char status)
  {
    switch (status)
    {
    case 'E': 
      this.m_error = s;
      System.out.println(s);
      showStatus(s);
      this.m_msgWindow.setTitle("Error Message");
      setWrapText(s);
      this.m_msgButton.setEnabled(true);
      this.m_msgWindow.show();
      return s;
    case 'M': 
      this.m_message = s;
      System.out.println(s);
      showStatus(s);
      this.m_msgWindow.setTitle("Information Message");
      setWrapText(s);
      this.m_msgButton.setEnabled(true);
      this.m_msgWindow.show();
      return s;
    case 'S': 
      this.m_message = s;
      System.out.println(s);
      showStatus(s);
      this.m_msgWindow.setTitle("Information Message");
      setWrapText(s);
      this.m_msgButton.setEnabled(false);
      this.m_msgWindow.show();
      return s;
    case 'D': 
      System.out.println(s);

      return s;
    }
    return "";
  }

  private void setWrapText(String s)
  {
    BreakIterator boundary = BreakIterator.getWordInstance(Locale.US);
    String line = "";

    int maxWidth = this.m_msgText.getSize().width;

    this.m_msgText.setText("");

    boundary.setText(s);
    int start = boundary.first();
    int end = boundary.next();
    while (end != -1)
    {
      String tmp = s.substring(start, end);
      if (this.m_msgMetrics.stringWidth(line + tmp) > maxWidth)
      {
        this.m_msgText.append(line + "\n");
        line = tmp;
      }
      else
      {
        line = line + tmp;
      }
      start = end;
      end = boundary.next();
      if (end == -1) {
        this.m_msgText.append(line);
      }
    }
    this.m_msgText.append(s.substring(start));
  }

  private void makeDirectories(String dir)
  {
    String fdir = dir;
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction()
    {
      private final String val$fdir="";

      public Object run()
      {
        String subdir = "";
        int i = this.val$fdir.indexOf('\\');
        while (i != -1)
        {
          subdir = this.val$fdir.substring(0, i);
          File f = new File(subdir);
          if (!f.isDirectory()) {
            f.mkdir();
          }
          i = this.val$fdir.indexOf('\\', i + 1);
        }
        return null;
      }
    });
  }

  private boolean verifyDataFile(String s)
  {
    String fs = s;
    Boolean retVal = 
      (Boolean)AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction()
      {
        private final String val$fs="";

        public Object run()
        {
          File f = new File(this.val$fs);
          if (!f.isFile()) {
            return new Boolean(false);
          }
          return new Boolean(true);
        }
      });
    return retVal.booleanValue();
  }

  private String verifyDataFilesInternal()
  {
    try
    {
      AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction()
      {
        public Object run()
        {
          File dir = new File(DataCache.this.m_dataDir);
          if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
          }
          return dir;
        }
      });
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(this.m_commandKey, ";");
      while (st.hasMoreElements())
      {
        String key = (String)st.nextElement();
        if (!verifyDataFile(this.m_dataDir + key + ".data")) {
          return "Data cache file " + this.m_dataDir + key + ".data could not be found.";
        }
        if (!verifyDataFile(this.m_dataDir + key + ".hash")) {
          return "Data cache file " + this.m_dataDir + key + ".hash could not be found.";
        }
      }
      return "";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return e.getMessage();
    }
  }

  private String loadAllDataInternal()
  {
    String status = "";
    String key = "";
    StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer("");
    Hashtable hash = null;

    alertStatus("loading data internal", 'D');
    URLConnection connection;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    try
    {
      if (this.m_servletURL.equals("")) {
        return alertStatus("Servlet URL not specified!", 'E');
      }
      try
      {
        URL inURL = new URL(this.m_servletURL);
        connection = inURL.openConnection();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return alertStatus("Error opening server connection: " + e.getMessage(), 'E');
      }
      try
      {
       // URLConnection connection;
        URL inURL;
        in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return alertStatus("Error opening input stream: " + e.getMessage(), 'E');
      }
      int count;
      try
      {
        count = Integer.parseInt((String)in.readObject());
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return alertStatus("Error getting object count: " + e.getMessage(), 'E');
      }

      this.m_XMLCache = new Hashtable(count, 1.0F);
      this.m_hashCache = new Hashtable(count, 1.0F);
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
      {
        key = "";
        data = new StringBuffer("");

        status = (String)in.readObject();
        alertStatus("read status", 'D');

        key = (String)in.readObject();
        alertStatus("read key", 'D');

        data = (StringBuffer)in.readObject();
        alertStatus("read data", 'D');

        hash = (Hashtable)in.readObject();
        alertStatus("read cache", 'D');
        if (status.equals("connection closed")) {
          return alertStatus("Error communicating with servlet: Connection is closed. Please re-login.", 'E');
        }
        if (status.equals("execution error")) {
          return alertStatus("Error in servlet: Error during execution of query. Please notify Data Management.", 'E');
        }
        if (data == null) {
          return alertStatus("Error communicating with servlet: There was a data transmission error. Please notify Data Management.", 'E');
        }
        alertStatus("got cache: " + key, 'D');
        this.m_XMLCache.put(key, data);
        this.m_hashCache.put(key, hash);
      }
      alertStatus("closing stream", 'D');


      in.close();

      return "";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return "Error in loadAllDataInternal: " + e.getMessage();
    }
  }

  private String openAllDataInternal(String path)
  {
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    String file = "";
    StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer("");
    Hashtable hash = null;
    String status = "";
    try
    {
      status = verifyDataFilesInternal();
      if (!status.equals("")) {
        return status;
      }
      StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(this.m_commandKey, ";");
      int len = st.countTokens();
      this.m_XMLCache = new Hashtable(len, 1.0F);
      this.m_hashCache = new Hashtable(len, 1.0F);
      while (st.hasMoreElements())
      {
        String key = (String)st.nextElement();

        file = path + key + ".data";
        in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        data = (StringBuffer)in.readObject();
        in.close();

        file = path + key + ".hash";
        in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        hash = (Hashtable)in.readObject();
        in.close();

        this.m_XMLCache.put(key, data);
        this.m_hashCache.put(key, hash);
      }
      return "";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return "Error in openAllDataInternal: " + e.getMessage();
    }
  }

  private String saveAllDataInternal(String s)
  {
    Enumeration keys = null;
    String file = "";
    StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer("");
    Hashtable hash = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    if (s.equals("")) {
      return alertStatus("Data file path is '': " + s, 'E');
    }
    try
    {
      keys = this.m_XMLCache.keys();
      makeDirectories(s);
      while (keys.hasMoreElements())
      {
        this.m_key = ((String)keys.nextElement());

        file = s + this.m_key;
        data = (StringBuffer)this.m_XMLCache.get(this.m_key);
        hash = (Hashtable)this.m_hashCache.get(this.m_key);

        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file + ".data"));
        out.writeObject(data);
        out.close();

        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file + ".hash"));
        out.writeObject(hash);
        out.close();
      }
      return "";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return "Error in saveAllDataInternal: " + e.getMessage();
    }
  }

  public String loadAllData(boolean verbose)
  {
    String s = 
      (String)AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction()
      {
        public Object run()
        {
          return DataCache.this.loadAllDataInternal();
        }
      });
    if (verbose) {
      if (s.equals("")) {
        alertStatus("Loaded all data!", 'M');
      } else {
        alertStatus(s, 'E');
      }
    }
    return s;
  }

  public String saveAllData(boolean verbose, String path)
  {
    String fpath = path;
    String s = 
      (String)AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction()
      {
        private final String val$fpath="";

        public Object run()
        {
          return DataCache.this.saveAllDataInternal(this.val$fpath);
        }
      });
    if (verbose) {
      if (s.equals("")) {
        alertStatus("Saved all data files!", 'M');
      } else {
        alertStatus(s, 'E');
      }
    }
    return s;
  }

  public String saveAllData(boolean verbose)
  {
    String s = 
      (String)AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction()
      {
        public Object run()
        {
          return DataCache.this.saveAllDataInternal(DataCache.this.m_dataDir);
        }
      });
    if (verbose) {
      if (s.equals("")) {
        alertStatus("Saved all data files!", 'M');
      } else {
        alertStatus(s, 'E');
      }
    }
    return s;
  }

  public String openAllData(boolean verbose)
  {
    String s = 
      (String)AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction()
      {
        public Object run()
        {
          return DataCache.this.openAllDataInternal(DataCache.this.m_dataDir);
        }
      });
    if ((s.equals("")) && (verbose)) {
      alertStatus("Opened all data files!", 'M');
    }
    return s;
  }

  public String verifyAllDataFiles(boolean verbose)
  {
    String s = verifyDataFilesInternal();
    if ((s.equals("")) && (verbose)) {
      alertStatus("Verified all data files!", 'M');
    }
    return s;
  }

  public void setCache(String key, boolean verbose)
  {
    this.m_currXMLCache = ((StringBuffer)this.m_XMLCache.get(key));
    this.m_currHashCache = ((Hashtable)this.m_hashCache.get(key));
    this.m_currCacheString = key;
    if (((this.m_currXMLCache == null) || (this.m_currHashCache == null)) && 
      (verbose)) {
      alertStatus("Requested cache (" + this.m_currCacheString + ") is null!", 'E');
    }
  }

  public String getXML(String key)
  {
    this.m_currXMLCache = ((StringBuffer)this.m_XMLCache.get(key));
    this.m_currHashCache = ((Hashtable)this.m_hashCache.get(key));
    this.m_currCacheString = key;

    return getXML();
  }

  public String getXML()
  {
    if (this.m_currXMLCache == null)
    {
      alertStatus("Current cache (" + this.m_currCacheString + ") is null!", 'E');
      return "";
    }
    return this.m_currXMLCache.toString();
  }

  public String lookupCacheValue(String code)
  {
    String[] values = (String[])this.m_currHashCache.get(code);
    return values[1];
  }

  private void printData(String[][] data)
  {
    alertStatus("printing data", 'D');
    for (int i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
      System.out.println("key: " + data[0][i] + "\tvalue: " + data[1][i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"..to replace with stjs"* What's that?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I just updated the question but stjs is http://st-js.github.io/

Comment: *"..any though if this is can be done thru stjs"* Not as far as I understand. One of the security features of JS is that it does not mess with local files! *"..or any other technology?"* Well that depends.. 1) Why are you transitioning from an applet (there are many good reasons, but please pin it down). 2) Does the utility that performs this action **have to** be **embedded in** the web page?